# Get particular string using regex java

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to know how to get the string out of a group of strings

```
String j = "<a ............> hai</a>";
```

I want to get the string for the tag

```
  <a ...> ... </a>
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. There are dozens of posts about this, just search and find out why.

Comment: Why did you remove the old question and replace it with a different question? All the answers below has become totally irrelevant because of you. -1 for making us looks like an idiot (even though I probably am an idiot).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an [XML parser](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) for that and extract the attributes in question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bozho. If you need to do this on a regular basis, an XML or HTML Parser would be much less error prone.

For a quick and dirty approach, you can use the Regex

```
(href|src)="[^"]*"
```

Make sure to escape all these quotes when trying that.

Answer (score 0):

I hate regex, I would have done it this way..

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("href="));
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\"", 5);  //'href=' is 5 chars 
//str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ");  //this is more readable I think
```

Do the same for `src=`

Note, you will get `href=` as part of the string as well, how to prevent that is left as an exercise. lol. (HINT: change `0` in the second line to ...)

Comment: In this case `str` will contain just `href=`, probably not what he wants.

Comment: You are right, duh!.. I fixed it.. (I think), didn't actually test it.